# How to return data from nested async function

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

```
async getSettlementByUser(email): Promise<any> {
    let listofTerminalId = [];
    // Get current user
    let user = await this.userModel.findOne({ email: email });
    // get list of sn
    let tpeIndexes = user.bindedSn.map((item) => item);
    //list des tpes binded to current user
    let tpe = tpeIndexes.map(async (index) => {
      let list = await this.tpeModel.find({ sn: index });
      // console.log('liste des tpes', list);
      let terminalId = list.map((item) => item.terminalId);
      // console.log('terminalId', ...terminalId);
      listofTerminalId.push(...terminalId);

      console.log('listofTerminalId', listofTerminalId);
      return await listofTerminalId.map(async (item) => {
        return await this.modelSettlement
          .find({ terminalID: item })
          .then((res) => res)
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      });
      // console.log('settlement', settlement);
      // return settlement;
    });

    let promiseValue = await Promise.all(tpe);
    console.log('promiseValue', promiseValue);
    // // return promiseValue;
    // return tpe;
  }
```

OUTPUT

```
promiseValue [   [ Promise { <pending> } ],   [ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ],   [
    Promise { <pending> },
    Promise { <pending> },
    Promise { <pending> }   ] ]
```

I used Promise.all() to handle this nested async still get this result so How can  I resolve this problem and why it shows this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `Promise.all` only on the outer layer of the nesting, not on the inner array of promises. You would *also* need to do

```
return Promise.all(listofTerminalId.map(async (item) => {
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^
  return this.modelSettlement
    .find({ terminalID: item })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}));
```

---

However, given the `listofTerminalId.push(...terminalId)`, it looks like you actually don't want any nesting. You may just want to

```
async getSettlementByUser(email): Promise<any> {
  // Get current user
  const user = await this.userModel.findOne({ email: email });

  // list des tpes binded to current user
  const tpes = await Promise.all(user.bindedSn.map(async (index) => {
    const list = await this.tpeModel.find({ sn: index });
    // console.log('liste des tpes', list);
    return list.map((item) => item.terminalId);
  }));
  const listofTerminalId = tpes.flat();
  console.log('listofTerminalId', listofTerminalId);

  const settlements = await Promise.all(listofTerminalId.map((item) => {
    return this.modelSettlement.find({ terminalID: item })
  }));
  console.log('settlements', settlements);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , could you give source where can I see advanced things in JS